# Is it possible to set Range object as "backwards selection"?

Tags: javascript, selection, range

I create a Range object and then add this Range to selection

```
window.getSelection ().addRange(myRange);
```

How to set the selection direction?
I mean direction which can be checked using the `anchorNode`, `anchorOffset`, `focusNode` and `focusOffset` properties of selections.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this on browsers that support the [`extend()`](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#dom-selection-extend) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection/extend)) method of `Selection` objects. Mozilla, WebKit and Opera support it; IE does not up to and including version 11. `extend()` has been added to the [HTML Editing APIs spec](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#concept-selection) so it may yet appear in IE.

Here's an example function:

```
function selectRangeBackwards(range) {
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (typeof sel.extend != "undefined") {
            var endRange = range.cloneRange();
            endRange.collapse(false);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(endRange);
            sel.extend(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IE10 does not support extend() method.

Comment: @Inez: Yeah. They ignored by [my bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/737106/implement-missing-extend-method-of-selection).

Comment: @TimDown I've just tested this method in Mircrosoft EDGE and it did work. Probably, they finally implemented extend() method.